# Querying _job data view is resulting DeliveredTime = Null

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I have a journey builder send in a child BU without using any publication list.
In the journey builder UI and email tracking, I can see that sends were being delivered and opened.

However, querying and joining the _job and _sent data view, I am getting null values for the _bob's DeliveredTime field.

Here is my query:

```
a.JobID,
a.SubscriberKey,
a.EventDate,
b.DeliveredTime,
b.EmailName,
a.AccountID
FROM
_sent a
INNER JOIN
_job b
ON a.JobID = b.JobID
WHERE
b.EmailName LIKE '%EmailName%'
```

Also, any idea why the _sent AccountID is returning the Parent's MID when I am querying in the child BU?
Adding the a.AccountID = MID of the child BU is not returning any rows at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

DeliveredTime is Null for you because this field is [not populated for Journey Builder sends](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/ideas/#deliverytime-for-journey-builder-emails).

Help me change it on [IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000001HkZgQAK).